# how to sracpe two key words at the same time from twitter using python snscrape

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to scrape both based on two text words that appears in the same tweet. For example, I want to know the tweets talked about the US jobs. I want to scrape 'US' and 'Job' same time. It did not need to appear one by one like US Job. I just want to find the tweet that these two appear together for example US today posts 1000 jobs. how to fix following code?

Thanks

```
for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('us' and 'job').get_items(),
sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('holiday' and 'party'):
    if i>1000:
        break
    attributes_container.append([tweet.user.username,
                                 tweet.content])
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a query that is identical to the query made by twitter in it's advanced search feature. So for searching for tweets that contain the words jobs and US its just "jobs US",  If you wanted only tweets from this year up until september 1st it would be "jobs US since:2022-01-01 until:2022-09-01"

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter

query = "jobs US"
tweets = []
limit = 100


for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items()):
    if i == limit:
        break
    print(tweet.content)
    tweets.append(tweet)
```